# Golang OpenAPI Generator add custom header to request

Tags: http, go, openapi, openapi-generator

Is it possible to add a custom header that is not specified in the `openapi.yaml` to the request?

I have something like:

```golang
res, err := s.client.MyApi.
        SomeOperation(context.Background(), id).
        SomeOperationRequest(req).
        Execute()
```

And I would like to add a header to this request. Is there something like "AddHeader()". Or can I pass it by context somehow?

I am using the OpenAPITools generator.

Answer (score 0):

if your `req` used for keep body params/headers only and underhood it implement `ClientRequestWriter` interface for create actual request (where request created from your object is used for: https://github.com/go-openapi/runtime/blob/da56347e36dc1a470118d4306d2821572c3ad14f/client/request.go#L107), if so, you can decorate `WriteToRequest` method (from ClientRequestWriter interface):

```
type decoratedRequest struct {
  SomeOperationRequest // it must be same type for which defined WriteToRequest method, probably it will be pointer to SomeOperationRequest type
  // here you can add custom headers params if you want
}

func (r *decoratedRequest) WriteToRequest(req ClientRequest, reg strfmt.Registry) error
 if err := r.SomeOperationRequest.WriteToRequest(req, reg); err != nil {
   return err
 }

//here you manualy edit actual request to the server
 return req.SetHeaderParam("your-header", "your-value")
}
```

and production code will look like:

```
res, err := s.client.MyApi.
        SomeOperation(context.Background(), id).
        SomeOperationRequest(decoratedRequest{SomeOperationRequest: req}).
        Execute()
```

PS: in your case to make the actual request to the server **may be** used another interface, but idea is the same

PSS: this will be work, but idiomatic way would be to edit openapi.yaml

Comment: I dont quite understand where you are taking the `WriteToRequest` method from. What is the `clientRequest`?

Comment: @JonathanR ClientRequestWriter - interface defined in go-openapi, according to go-openapi source code i suggest that your request should implement it, for creating actual request look here: https://github.com/go-openapi/runtime/blob/da56347e36dc1a470118d4306d2821572c3ad14f/client/request.go#L107       if it true you can decorate your request as i described above

Comment: I don't use go-openapi. I use openapi-generator.

Answer (score 0):

Add custom headers to the DefaultHeader map before calling the API

```
s.client.GetConfig().DefaultHeader["some-header"] = "value"
```